# Pinterest image is blank despite og:image tag on page

Tags: facebook-opengraph, pinterest

On this page > http://matchcoverguy.com/kimballs-ice-cream-1920s-tall-universal/

When I click the "Pin It" button, the popup that appears has a blank image. Although, I have an open graph metatag there:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://matchcoverguy.com/wp-content/uploads/Kimballs.jpg"/>
```

Is there something else I can do to get the Pin-it button to pull the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image violates the 3:1 maximum image ratio;

It's also missing other tags, see http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug for more information (though that tool doesn't currently mention the 3:1 max image ratio, it's mentioned in the docs)

Comment: I'm confused ... the question is about Pinterest, not Facebook, yet you reference a FB dev doc?

Comment: This was over three years ago, the original poster accepted this answer so i guess it also fixed their problem with Pinterest even though it was Facebook's debug tool I mentioned here) - I recommend asking a new question with specific info if your issue is specific to Pinterest